# Should I merge identity server database with application database?

Tags: asp.net, oauth, identityserver4, openid-connect

I recently started from scratch to implement a new application, so I have created a new application with its own database and I used Identity Server 4 with ASP.NET Identity which has a separate persistence database and I named it Identity_Server.

The plan is that in near future I will start developing another applications which will be clients in the central Identity service provider (Identity Server 4).

The problem which I'm facing right now, in the application I'm developing I have auditing columns like CreatedById & LastUpdatedById which will capture the user id. As will as I will have a logs table where I will store the user id as a foreign key.
Storing user ids is not a problem because I can capture it once user logged into the application but the problem that in UI I wanted to present more meaningful claim like username or full name.

how I can make the relation between application entities and identity server user entity where both are in separate db context and separate physical databases.

Shall I change the architecture and keep all my applications entities in same database with identity server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the information of the user is not part of the context.

Mixing the two contexts is not going to help you and querying both contexts is not the solution. *The solution is to make sure that the information becomes part of the context.*

This is in fact how Identity works. When you login with an external provider, like Google, a local copy of the user is created in the AspNetUsers table. Redundant? No, because that is another context, which you don't have access to.

In case you want to show user info on a report, you'll need to create a local copy of the user including the relevant information.

Please note that there may be information of the current user available in the claims. But as you need information from other users as well, you'll need to store it in the business context.

You can either choose some strategy to read information from claims when the user logs in, calling a UserInfo endpoint (if consent is given) or add functionality to maintain the user information in the business context.

*Bottom line is that you'll need to create a User table in the business context that contains the information you need for reports.*

Comment: I'm totally convinced with your answer, I was thinking about this as well.. it's only I have to think in how to came up with a strategy on how to keep users info table in sync in business databases.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I want to start developing using a single database, and at the same time, I want it to be friendly with future database concerns-based separation. Should I follow the exact approach when databases are separated ?? e.g., creating two users table, one for identity and another for application (without identity info)?